# Why Can't i create columns with grid?

Tags: html, css

I've been having problems to create multiple columns in my site using html and CSS with grid, for some reason the command `grid-template-rows:2` does not create a second column, but when I try with flexboxes it does create multiple columns.

```css
.first-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 2;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="first-container">
    <!--<div class = "tittle"><h1>Controle Digital Web 1.0</h1></div>-->
    <div class="boxes-box-1">
      <div class="subtittles">
        <h3>Subtittle 1:</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes-box-2">
      <div class="subtittles">
        <h3>Subtittle 2:</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes-box-3">
      <div class="subtittles">
        <h3>Subtittle 3:</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxes-box-4">
      <div class="subtittles">
        <h3>Subtittle 4:</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Results with the code:
[img-grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65m8w.png)

Results changing the code to display with flexboxes:
[img-flex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X10m.png)

Comment: `grid-template-rows:2` isn't valid CSS, it has no effect no matter what the value of `display` is. It isn't possible to explain how to user Grid for this without giving a complete introductory tutorial to using Grid. There are plenty of those out there already. Try reading one of them.

Comment: Read more about *CSS-Grid* here (Complete Documentation). https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try using this code:

```
 .first-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
  /* grid-template-rows: 0px 0px; */
  }
```